# Line for signature in markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm writing a document using markdown, which I'm exporting to a PDF using pandoc. At the end of the document I need to have space for signatures on a printed copy of the PDF.

I've tried to find how to draw a line with a fixed width, but so far I only got to escaping the underscore character, which doesn't feel quite right. It's as if I'm missing something, this couldn't possibly be that unusual to want to do.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is unlikely that a single feature that compiles to both HTML and PDF will work for you since this is too specific.

If you want to do that, you probably need to use raw latex and raw HTML, since latex will be ignored when compiling to HTML and HTML tags will be ignored when compiling to PDF.

For example, to get what you want on both HTML and PDF do:

```
<div style="width:200px"><hr/></div>

\noindent\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}
```

Other options include:

- use a pre-processor on top of the Pandoc and small build script
- use a markdown compiler that supports custom extensions

Comment: Works great! I even added some Latex like `\vspace{10 mm}` to add some vertical space between the signature lines